# what happens when there's only one build type (release) in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

my app's build.gradle has only the ***release*** build type inside the  buildTypes  section:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Does this mean i **don't** have a ***debug*** buildtype ? or is ***debug*** implied someway ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean i don't have a debug buildtype ?

No.

When a new module is created, Android Studio automatically creates the debug and release build types. Adding it to the build.gradle is necessary if you want to want to add or change certain settings.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types):

> The debug build type doesn't appear in the build configuration file,
>   Android Studio configures it with debuggable true. This allows you to
>   debug the app on secure Android devices and configures APK signing
>   with a generic debug keystore.
>
> You can add the debug build type to your configuration if you want to
>   add or change certain settings.